# compare oracle 11g performance statistics ASM-FileSystem

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, statistics, database-performance

Im pretty new to oracle databases. The situation I have right now is that I need to extract and compare read/write performance statistics between File System and ASM in Oracle 11g Database Infrastructure R2.

I currently have two virtual machines, one is configured as File System and the other one is ASM (diskgroups are ok and good to go). Both running win7 pro x64 in separate physical HDDs on my computer.

The test that I came up with is to create a table in both DBs, and using a custom sequence I created, insert 100,000 records on them. Next thing, I will need to see how well did ASM performed compared to File System in terms of performance.

The problem? I dont know how to pull the performance statistics so that I can compare them. Can someone please help? It'll be much appreciated.

```
SQL> create sequence SQX
     start with 1
     increment by 1;

SQL> create table test(
     x number(9),
     y date);

SQL> begin
     for i in 1.. 100000 loop
     insert into test(x,y) values(SQX.nextval,sysdate);
     end loop;
     end;
     /
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that just using "autotrace" enabled me to see and compare some low level statistics between the two servers. Running "complex" select (I had to add three more tables that I could play with using different kind of joins) and update queries showed me huge differences between FS and ASM performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the good method. The performance of the I/O system can be only evaluated with specific tools such as ORION (and some others).

This article from Tim Hall gives you a good overview of the possibilities you have: [http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/measuring-storage-performance-for-oracle-systems.php].

Regards,
Cyryl

Comment: I'd prefer to see some more explanation of why the OP's proposal isn't a good solution in a good answer.